# Grid view row command showing error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I am getting this error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using `<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>` in configuration or `<%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %>` in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation` method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

This is my code:

```
protected void GridViewCommandEventHandler(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "view")
    {
        int row_id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        var result = (from test in je.jobposting where test.id==row_id select                test).FirstOrDefault();
        Session["id"] = result;
    }
    else
    {
        int row_id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        var result = (from test in je.jobposting where test.id==row_id select test).FirstOrDefault();
        je.DeleteObject(result);
        je.SaveChanges();
        Response.Redirect ("");
    }
}
```

Comment: see msdn [page.enableeventvalidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx), can you provide client part of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `EnableEventValidation` property of page in aspx file to false

Comment: But I dont want to set event validation to false for security reasons.. is there any other process..??

Comment: make sure that u r binding the gridview only when its not a postback for example 

`if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
....
gridview1.DataSource=someDataSource;
gridview1.DataBind();
....
}`

Comment: public void showgv()
    {
        var mail = lblmail.Text;
        var result = (from test in je.jobposting orderby test.post_date where test.c_j_email == mail select test).ToList();
        foreach (var items in result)
        {
            gvjob.DataSource = result;
            gvjob.DataBind();
        }
    }

Comment: if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           
            showgv();
          
        }

Comment: i think everything is fine and it should work, still take a look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397(v=vs.110).aspx) to use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation`

Comment: check this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitsh/archive/2007/07/31/why-i-get-invalid-postback-or-callback-argument-errors.aspx) also, it can be helpful